# CSS Flex column wrap doesnt work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't make wrap the divs into columns.
Here is my code

```
.hosts.body
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    flex-wrap: wrap
    justify-content: flex-start
    align-content: flex-start
    align-items: flex-start

    .server
      border-left: 0.3em solid $green
      padding: 0.3em
      color: $green
      margin: 0.1em
      background: #c8e6c9
      min-width: 12em
      max-width: 12em
      overflow: hidden
```

Link: http://codepen.io/CJRoman/pen/YXNGGq

What i'm doing wrong? I can't find out what it needs additionally to wrap.

Comment: If you remove `flex-direction: column` from your body css then your columns wrap just fine.

Comment: But now it is `row` direction

Comment: you have to give your `.body` element a specific height. Here is an example with a `height: 60vh;`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVWRxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set a height to containing `flexbox` element,

try modifying like this:

```
  .body
display: flex
flex-direction: column
flex-wrap: wrap
justify-content: flex-start
align-content: flex-start
align-items: flex-start
height: 500px
```

---

this **[fiddle](http://codepen.io/maio/pen/VLPKGP)** is a little different but it's just to give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

`flex-direction: column` means the child-element will align from top to bottom and every one will occupy one line,you can remove it because of the default value is `flex-direction: row`,which means every child-element will display in one line if the width of flex-container is big enough